# Get to the child element of input tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get to `<label>` tag right under the `<input>` tag for later styling purposes. I tried with `.firstElementChild`, which gives me a `null` value. How can I get to label tag of clicked checkbox field? This is my code:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");


for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i]);
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    var targetCb = e.target;

    console.log(targetCb.firstElementChild);

  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title mb-3">STYLISTIC SET</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet1" name="sSet1" value="sSet1" />
    <label for="sSet1">Stylistic set 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet2" name="sSet2" value="sSet2" />
    <label for="sSet2">Stylistic set 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet3" name="sSet3" value="sSet3" />
    <label for="sSet3">Stylistic set 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet4" name="sSet4" value="sSet4" />
    <label for="sSet4">Stylistic set 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: an input has no child element ... it has a `nextElementSibling` though

Comment: the label is not a _child_ of the input, it's a _sibling_. A child is an element _within_ another element - e.g. the `<input>` and `<label>` elements are both children of of the `<li>` because they are wrapped inside each other. Whereas elements which are adjacent and have the same parent are siblings (just like in a real-life family). If you get your terminology right then suddenly the problem will become quite simple to research and solve.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the wrong terminology....you should put it as an answer.

Comment: well I only gave you a hint, I didn't actually tell you the correct code solution, so I'm not sure it qualifies as an answer.

Comment: Alright than. Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you quite don't know what `child elements` and `siblings` are.

Consider the following for children:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">I'm the child of my parent.</div>
</div>
```

And the following for siblings:

```
<div id="sibling1"></div>
<div id="sibling2">I'm the sibling of sibling1.</div>
```

In your code, those `label`s are **siblings** of your `input` elements.

So in your script, change `console.log(targetCb.firstElementChild);` to `console.log(targetCb.nextElementSibling);`

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");


for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i]);
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    var targetCb = e.target;

    console.log(targetCb.nextElementSibling);

  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title mb-3">STYLISTIC SET</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet1" name="sSet1" value="sSet1" />
    <label for="sSet1">Stylistic set 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet2" name="sSet2" value="sSet2" />
    <label for="sSet2">Stylistic set 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet3" name="sSet3" value="sSet3" />
    <label for="sSet3">Stylistic set 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sSet4" name="sSet4" value="sSet4" />
    <label for="sSet4">Stylistic set 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`var targetCb = e.target;`
to `var targetCb = e.target.nextElementSibling;`

Comment: downvote for complete lack of any explanation of what the code is, or does, or why it should be used, or why the OP is on the wrong track (e.g. incorrect understanding of DOM terminology). Code-only answers are not a lot of use to people who may not understand them. It just encourages cargo-cult programming.

Comment: Changed. And now anyone who can read english-based code can understand. (On another note, you actually downvoted my answer a fraction of a second after I posted it. I would expect people not to be so trigger-happy)

Comment: Why? If your answer isn't ready for people to judge, don't post it. Your new version is much more succinct, but you still don't have an actual explanation of your change. The whole problem here is that the OP doesn't seem to understand about children and siblings. Your answer assumes they'll implicitly understand why your code is the correct solution. But if they don't understand what a DOM sibling actually is, why should they understand the changed code?

Comment: @ADyson, my friend...: seems to me you are assuming people who ask questions are not intelligent enough to understand the difference between "child" and "sibling". Furthermore, I didn't come here to write a book on the DOM, just to give a simple answer to a simple question. Besides, Jaromanda had already hinted that.

Comment: No, I'm assuming they're not experts in the relevant technology and terminology to be able to figure out why your answer is relevant, and thus whether they should even bother to try it. And your answer doesn't mention child, so you haven't helped them to make that connection. Programming is all about precision and clarity. Inference and assumption has no place, no matter how intelligent anyone is. [CodeF0x's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892016/5947043) is an excellent model answer, btw.

Comment: That's a fallacious argument, as an expert would never come here asking this type of question. You didn't address the fact that I was pointing to the semantic difference between the english word "child" and the english word "sibling". If someone isn't able to make that leap, then nobody can help them.

Comment: _"an expert would never come here asking this type of question"_ ...which is exactly why you should not assume any knowledge on the part of the asker, or require them to infer anything in your answer. That's been my point from the beginning. _"the fact that I was pointing to the semantic difference between the english word "child" and the english word "sibling"."_...no, you didn't do that, you just wrote some code with no explanation. It doesn't point to anything, if you don't already know that "sibling" is a meaningful term in this context.

Comment: Anyway, I suspect we're going to have to agree to disagree, so my final word on the topic is to ask you to check which of the two answers to this question has got the most votes, and to consider why you think that might be the case. Thanks for the debate.

Comment: Yes, @ADyson: we agree to disagree. BTW, I myself upvoted CodeF0x answer.